# Why is it possible to leave CHROOT with this sftp config?

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, chroot, sftp

I'm trying to create the user lenny, that has read and write permissions in the folder `/home/lenny/` and has no shell but only access via SFTP. I'm doing the following:

```
useradd lenny
mkdir /home/lenny
usermod -d /home/lenny lenny
passwd lenny
chown lenny:lenny /home/lenny
chmod 755 /home/lenny
usermod -s /bin/false myuser
```

I then modified `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp`  

Match User lenny
ChrootDirectory /home/lenny
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Now when I do `sftp lenny@server` I can leave the CHROOT easily by doing `cd /` and `ls -la`, I see everything!

Why is that??? I don't get it, configuration should be okay, or am I wrong?

Comment: Probably, you should add "AllowTcpForwarding no" and "X11Forwarding no" to the "Match User" section.

Comment: @jofel I tried it with these two settings, it didn't work either.

Comment: What version of sshd are you running? The version of the ssh package is sufficient.

Comment: @uther It's actually a Kubuntu 11.10 with openssh. Version is 5.8p1-7ubuntu1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you restart the sshd service after making the changes to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?

`sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`

Ensure the chroot directory for the sftp user (in this case `/home/lenny`) is owned by root, not the sftp user. `chmod 755` is correct.

Also, I would add the following two lines for additional security:

```
Match User lenny
    ChrootDirectory /home/lenny
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
```

Restart your sshd service and you should have the desired chroot.

Comment: Yes, I did a restart and reload, didn't work.

Comment: See my additional edit. The directory should be owned by root. I missed that the first time and it was staring me in the face.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it! One further question, how can I give lenny read and write permissions below /home/lenny?

Comment: So user lenny cannot upload files or create directories in `/home/lenny`? Make sure `/home/lenny` group ownership is `lenny` and `chmod 775 /home/lenny`.